# SDL2 Hello World tutorial closes with error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

I'm developing in VS2013 on a Windows 8.1 machine. The window flashes briefly on the screen (despite having a 2 second delay in the code).

Here is all the code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
    std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 4;
}

//open a window
SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (win == nullptr){
    std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 3;
}

//renderer
SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
if (ren == nullptr){
    std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 2;
}

//load bitmap
SDL_Surface *bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("helloworld.jpg");
if (bmp == nullptr){
    std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 6;
}

SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);
if (tex == nullptr){
    std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 5;
}

SDL_RenderClear(ren);
SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

SDL_Delay(2000);


return 0;
}
```

It exits with a code 6. I was thinking it couldn't find the helloworld.jpg file. But, its there. I moved it from location to location hoping I was just an idiot. No luck. Its currently in the same directory as the .exe file.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?  What happened when you did, and stepped through the code?  At which point did it act unexpectedly?  What else did you try?

Comment: Make sure that the process's current working directory is the one in which you are executing the file.  And, I'm going to say it, but check the file name and extension again.  I've been tripped up by this before.

Answer (score 2):

SDL_LoadBMP will only load BMP formatted pictures, and guessing by the extension you have chosen you look to be using a JPEG formatted image, and your program is refusing to load it.

see [SDL_Image](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/11/sdl2-loading-images-with-sdlimage.html) for one possible solution.

Comment: The program even tells the OP it did so: `return 6;`, the quickly disappearing window is just the console popping up, printing "SDL_LoadBMP Error: ..", noticing the program has exited, and closing *that* window right away.